# Debug react js from VS Code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug in VS Code. However none of my breakpoints are getting hit. Followed several tutorials like this one: https://scotch.io/tutorials/debugging-create-react-app-applications-in-visual-studio-code to no avail.

```
yarn start-app:
```

[image]

Any breakpoints I have selected are skipped:

[image: r]